# How can I change a label when other labels change?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to make a label change when other 2 labels change. The 2 labels constantly change randomly.

Here's the code:`if ([labes.text isEqualToString:@"haha"] && [alizz.text isEqualToString:@"hoho"]) {
        laab.text = @"hello";
    }`

Maybe refreshing every 0.0005 seconds will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you are changing other two labels? you can add some function that update you third label just after updating the other two.

Comment: i'm using a pickerview and i just connected those two lables.

Comment: Means you are changing those two labels on pickerview delegate pickerView didSelectRow:inComponent. In the same delegate you can update the third label. if you can provide some code the i would be helpful.

Comment: `- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if([pickerView isEqual: picker]){
        labes.text= [countryNames objectAtIndex:row];
    }
       if([pickerView isEqual: sndpicker]){
        alizz.text= [newArraya objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}
`

Answer (score 0):

You Can try nstimer for call method in time intervel.